# Best way to automate the environment setup/update from a git repo?

Tags: php, mysql, git, ant, continuous-integration

I have the following setup: A local debian maschine with a LAMP setup. Now I need to work with a PHP project which is administered via git (or GitLab in special).

If I (or other developers) join the project, I must do several thinks:

- Create a MySQL database
- Import the MySQL schema
- Create a vHost for Apache
- ...

If I update the project after a time of inactivity, I must update several thinks:

- Changes in MySQL schema
- Insert/Update/Delete records
- ...

And this must to be done by every single developer. Now I search a solution to automate this workflow. I once considered Apache Ant and I think the tool can create a solution.

In the Ant file I can create workflows for the database, the vhost and other things. Additional I need a tool to manage MySQL migrations (Phinx maybe?). This tool can I trigger by Ant also, so I can automate the MySQL updates in/after a checkout process.

But this complete idea is created by myself. I have no experience with such kinds of processes. And it is very hard to search for this topic if you dont have any experience because I found so many topics and sides about continuous integration, continuous delivery, different tools so that I cant separate what is relevant for my need.

Unfortunately I need help and advice to find the right/best way for my case.

PS: Sorry for any grammar mistakes. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to manage local development environments, gaining popularity recently, is using some kind of *virtualization*, via VMs or containers. [Vagrant](https://vagrantup.com) and [Docker](https://docker.com) are two most popular solutions. Usually they are accompanied by a provisioner tools, like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Chef](https://chef.io). The idea is that you'll need to maintain in an actual state an image (or multiple images) of your development environment. Newcommers will need to install the same tool and bootstrap the environment. [Dig](https://box.scotch.io/) [the](https://github.com/sapienza/vagrant-php-box) [internet](https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/development-environments-with-vagrant-and-puppet/) to [find](https://docs.docker.com/opensource/project/set-up-dev-env/) [more](https://medium.com/on-docker/development-environments-with-docker-89657c7b4ea2#.7m8er2yj3).

If you containerize and version your DB this way, you won't need any migration tools at all (hopefully): the tool of your choice will handle versions by design. But you will be still free to use Phinx or other solution, like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org) or [FlyWay](https://flywaydb.org/). The migrations is this case can be versioned with Git, next to your main code base.